# .Net - General numeric formatting does not seem to preserve zeros

Tags: c#, .net, number-formatting

Looking at [the documentation on Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString). It says

> However, if the number is a Decimal and the precision specifier is omitted, fixed-point notation is always used and trailing zeros are preserved.

To me, the definition of trailing zeros just means any zeros at the end of a number, regardless of whether they are before or after the decimal point.

So, 300 and 3.00 both have 2 trailing zeros based on my understanding of trailing zeros.

However, when I actually try it out, it seems that only trailing zeros before the decimal point are preserved.

Am I just misunderstanding the definition of trailing zeros here, or is there a case where zeros after the decimal will be preserved?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Decimal(10.000).ToString("G"));
        Console.WriteLine(new Decimal(0.000000).ToString("G"));
        Console.WriteLine(new Decimal(30000).ToString("G"));
    }
}
```

See example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/O2GwOY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the number as `decimal` but as `double` literal. 
Since `double` does not preserve trailing zeroes, the constructor does not see them. For the first two examples you are using the constructor

```
public Decimal (double value)
```

and for the last one

```
public Decimal (int value)
```

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine(10.000m.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(0.000000m.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(30000m.ToString("G"));
```

The `m` type suffix ("m" for money) specifies a `decimal` number. This works as expected.

This works as well:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("10.0000").ToString("G")
```

or

```
Decimal.Parse("10.0000").ToString("G")
```

See: [Value types table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table)